# Natbib: How can I generate the bibliography like this: Last name, First name.

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I use natbib package to generate the bibliography, but I found the package put the first name of the author first, like L.H. Han. I hope the format can be in this way: Han, L.H.

How can I change the format? Thanks!

sample.bib:

```
@article{han2003experimental,
  title={{An experimental study and calculation on the fire resistance of concrete-filled SHS and RHS columns}},
  author={Han, L.H. and Yang, Y.F. and Xu, L.},
  journal={Journal of Constructional Steel Research},
  volume={59},
  number={4},
  pages={427--452},
  issn={0143-974X},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

sample.tex

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, titlepage, oneside, final]{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage[colon,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig,subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

Test\citet{han2003experimental}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{BibFile}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Bibliography}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use the `custombib` package to define your own .bst file. It offers various alternatives for the order of first and surname, initials with or without dot, full first names ...

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be... use biblatex!
You can change the way the bibliography is sorted and the way it appears very easily. Moreover, it is compatible with natbib (even if you don't have the possibility to use the most out of biblatex in compatibility mode). 
Try it out, it is very easy to use.

Comment: So how to tune biblatex (maybe, which style to use?) in order to achieve the "LastName FirstName" format?